# Free App Virtualization Software

Tags: windows, virtualization

In my attempts to run a Windows program on a raspberry pi, I think my reading has brought me to app virtualization.

If I have the program installed on a Windows computer on the same network as a Linux machine, then an app virtualization software should span the gap, right? If so, are there such things as free APP virtualization software out there?

Comment: I think the answer to your first question is 'no'. If you ask what you're actually trying to achieve, someone may be able to help. Google 'xy problem' to see why I suggest that

Comment: Your program is running on a MS Windows computer. So why do you want to use a virtualization application? It only makes sense if you want to run the MS Windows program on the RasPi with annoying slow speed.

Comment: Bingo! 

Ingo you’re on the money. I want to run the MS Windows program on the Pi. 

Slow speed is acceptable.

Comment: what windows program are you trying to run?

Comment: It was brought up in the other forum (before this was migrated) and really didn't solve my problem-

I'm trying to run Quick Books on a the Pi on a workstation that ONLY gets used for Quickbooks...and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate software for Windows 98 or 3.1, but because of system requirements you cannot virtualize anything that requires more ram / CPU. Use qemu as it is great for emulating most platforms.